# ListPopupWindow getListView returns nullpointerexception after creation

Tags: java, android

I'm using the `ListPopupWindow`:

```
@NonNull
private ListPopupWindow createListPopupWindow() {
    ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(mContext);
    listPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_dropdown));
    listPopupWindow.setDropDownGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    listPopupWindow.setWidth(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
    listPopupWindow.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
    listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
    return listPopupWindow;
}
```

And when I try to call:

```
listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new DropDownlistAdapter(mContext,
                armAwayItems));
View container = (View) listPopupWindow.getListView().getParent();
```

It always returns `NPE`, but this method already exists in the `ListPopupWindow`:

```
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.widget.ListView.getParent()' on a null object reference
```

The same when I try to call

```
listPopupWindow.getListView().setDividerHeight(1);
```

and

```
listPopupWindow.getListView().setDivider(...);
```

So `listPopupWindow.getListView()` always returns NULL.

Comment: where you called `show();` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(listPopupWindow != null){
listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new DropDownlistAdapter(mContext,
            armAwayItems));
View container = (View) listPopupWindow.getListView().getParent();
```

[What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

For those who look for answer in answer section (however M D's comment was much much earlier):

getListView() will return null until you call show() method of the listPopupWindow